# Windows Internet Explorer 11 Update error

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-update

In the last few days I had problems with IE. IE start for 1 second and immediately close (1st Issue), furthermore IE11 Windows Update fails with code 9C48 (2nd issue)

To fix this issue I have searched all over the net and applied all the proposed solutions, including many FixIt, Deactivate/Reactivate IE, sfc /scannow (3th issue), Unisntalling IE etc..all filed.

Finally I had found a tool (tweaking.com - Windows Repair All in one) that solve the First issue problem.

Now there are still two problems - Windows Update IE11 fails with code 9C48, and the `sfc /scannow` fail at 14%

If you search the web for the error 9C48, there are many other people with the exact same issue, but I am unable to apply the proposed solutions to my case and after a little investigation i have found this strange situation:

From IE -> About Internet Explorer -> Version Installed 11.0.9600.17**358**

From the binary iexplorer.exe -> Properties -> Details Tab -> Version Installed 11.0.9600.17**280**

From Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> View Installed Update -> I can see only Windows Internet Explore **10** ...
So i'm little bit confuse.

For the `sfc /scannow` fail, I have no idea. Here's the CBS.log

```
POQ 18 ends.
2014-10-23 16:35:12, Info                  CSI    00000054 [SR] Verify complete
2014-10-23 16:35:12, Info                  CSI    00000055 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2014-10-23 16:35:12, Info                  CSI    00000056 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2014-10-23 16:35:13, Info                  CSI    00000057 Repair results created:
POQ 19 starts:

POQ 19 ends.
2014-10-23 16:35:13, Info                  CSI    00000058 [SR] Verify complete
2014-10-23 16:35:14, Info                  CSI    00000059 [SR] Verifying 100 (0x0000000000000064) components
2014-10-23 16:35:14, Info                  CSI    0000005a [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    0000005b [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:20{10}]"pcasvc.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Program-Compatibility-Assistant, Version = 6.1.7601.18526, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    0000005c [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:30{15}]"setupcompat.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    0000005d [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:42{21}]"DVDPlaybackCompat.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    0000005e [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:28{14}]"hwcompat64.txt" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    0000005f [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:28{14}]"hwcompat32.txt" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000060 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:36{18}]"SBCompatPlugin.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000061 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:30{15}]"TouchCompat.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000062 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:34{17}]"wicainventory.exe" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000063 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:20{10}]"DevInv.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000064 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"sdbapiu.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000065 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"cosquery.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000066 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:38{19}]"compatResources.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000067 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:42{21}]"MediaCenterCompat.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000068 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:32{16}]"compatplugin.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000069 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:34{17}]"QueryAppBlock.exe" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    0000006a [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:28{14}]"compatctrl.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    0000006b [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"wdscore.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    0000006c [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:30{15}]"hwexclude32.txt" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    0000006d [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:30{15}]"hwexclude64.txt" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    0000006e [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:28{14}]"generaltel.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    0000006f [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:18{9}]"aeinv.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000070 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:16{8}]"wica.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000071 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:40{20}]"GadgetCompliance.dll" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Upgrade-Compat-Telemetry, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000072 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:26{13}]"sysmain64.sdb" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Telemetry-SDBs, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000073 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:26{13}]"sysmain32.sdb" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Telemetry-SDBs, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000074 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:40{20}]"sysmain32runtime.sdb" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Telemetry-SDBs, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000075 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:26{13}]"drvmain64.sdb" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Telemetry-SDBs, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000076 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:26{13}]"drvmain32.sdb" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Telemetry-SDBs, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000077 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:40{20}]"sysmain64runtime.sdb" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Telemetry-SDBs, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000078 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:26{13}]"sysmain64.sdb" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Telemetry-SDBs, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    00000079 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:26{13}]"sysmain32.sdb" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Telemetry-SDBs, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    0000007a [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:40{20}]"sysmain32runtime.sdb" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Telemetry-SDBs, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    0000007b [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:26{13}]"drvmain64.sdb" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Telemetry-SDBs, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    0000007c [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:26{13}]"drvmain32.sdb" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Telemetry-SDBs, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Info                  CSI    0000007d [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:40{20}]"sysmain64runtime.sdb" of Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Telemetry-SDBs, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Error                 CSI    0000007e (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #1340953# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectFileSystemProvider::SysCreateFile(flags = (AllowSharingViolation), handle = {provider=NULL, handle=0}, da = (SYNCHRONIZE|FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES), oa = @0xedcb40->OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES {s:48; rd:NULL; on:[122]"\??\C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-a..ence-telemetry-sdbs_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.18635_none_66352fe660ac93de"; a:(OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE)}, iosb = @0xedcb20, as = (null), fa = 0, sa = (FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE|FILE_SHARE_DELETE), cd = FILE_OPEN, co = (FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT|0x00004000), eab = NULL, eal = 0, disp = Invalid)
[gle=0xd0000034]
2014-10-23 16:35:15, Error                 CSI    0000007f@2014/10/23:14:35:15.856 (F) d:\win7sp1_gdr\base\wcp\sil\merged\ntu\ntsystem.cpp(2057): Error STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND originated in function Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectFileSystemProvider::SysCreateFile expression: (null)
[gle=0x80004005]
2014-10-23 16:35:17, Error                 CSI    00000080 (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #1340952# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::CDirectory::OpenExistingDirectory(...)[gle=0xd0000034]
2014-10-23 16:35:17, Error                 CSI    00000081 (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #1340951# from Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::CDirectory_IRtlDirectoryTearoff::OpenExistingDirectory(flags = 0, da = (SYNCHRONIZE), oa = @0xedd438->SIL_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES {s:40; on:"amd64_microsoft-windows-a..ence-telemetry-sdbs_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.18635_none_66352fe660ac93de"; a:(OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE)}, sa = (FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE|FILE_SHARE_DELETE), oo = (FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE|FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT|FILE_OPEN_FOR_BACKUP_INTENT), dir = NULL, disp = Invalid)
[gle=0xd0000034]
2014-10-23 16:35:17, Error                 CSI    00000082 (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #1340947# from CFileInstaller::DoComponentOperation(...)[gle=0xd0000034]
2014-10-23 16:35:17, Error                 CSI    00000083 (F) STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND #1340946# from PrimitiveInstaller::CCoordinator::RepairComponent(Component = Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience-Telemetry-SDBs, Version = 6.1.7601.18635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral)[gle=0xd0000034]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I recommend using Chrome or Firefox in your case.

Comment: lol..this is not a solution in my case

Comment: That's why i posted it as a comment.

Comment: @fasenderos You should try posting this question on Superuser. It seems more on-topic on that SE.

Comment: @Frunk I usually use chrome, but for my work I need IE because some italian government sites require IE to use their tools (thanks for that Italy).

Comment: @helrich ok i'll try on Superuser.